# How to change the layout resource folder at runtime?

Tags: android, layout

For example, there are two folders

`layout-mdpi`

`layout-hdpi`

How can I tell the OS, that the layout shall be taken from the other folder?

Comment: i think... never. If you could do that the idea of different layouts for different screen sizes is obsolete as you can store also anything in normal layout folder and select the right resource at runtime.

Comment: Is there a reason for doing this?

Comment: impossible. To add a file on res folder, you need to recompile your project, because the R.java class will be re-generate with the new id-codes for the new files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't. The reason is that it is read only system.